Color mapping incorrectly from shapefile in ggplot
I have this map with a shapefile I built, intersected with species occurrence data. It's mapping correctly except the coloring is wrong. There should only be 1 point of purple, because that would match the data table.

This is my current code:

library(viridis) 
# Plot with labels
oslo_map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp2_oslo, color = "gray30", size = 0.2, fill = "lightblue1") +
  geom_sf(data = intersect3_oslo, aes(color = occurrences), size = 1.5, fill = NA) +
  scale_color_viridis(option = "plasma", begin = 0, end = 1, direction = -1) +  # Adding color scale for points
  ggtitle("Oslo") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),  # Remove x-axis title
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),  # Remove y-axis title
        plot.title.position = "panel",  # Position the title centered above the plot
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)  # Center the title text
)

print(oslo_map)



It's still not mapping correctly, even though the table looks fine and I feel like the code makes sense. Any suggestions?

Could you edit your question to include reproducible data so that others can recreate the issue? Posting data as an image is highly discouraged. Good luck!

Hi @jpsmith, I am not sure how to do this without entering ~500 loc and a shapefile

In this case, you could try to recreate the issue using a publicly available dataset/shapefile, you could link to your files on GitHub, etc. But it will likely be very difficult for anyone to help you with out being able to recreate the issue

Maybe some features are not points but multipoints?

@VinceGreg Yes! actually you are right, some are multipoint and some are point. Any suggestions on how to deal with that? (i.e. there are 11 points on the graph and 11 rows, but three of the rows have multipoint geometry and the other 8 have point geometry)

Check for st_cast(df, "POINT")    See   . You might need to count your occurence again.
